# Why Chrome Canary is not supporting my threejs AR [ARCore] web application?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, arcore, webxr

I'm developing a **WebAR app using three.ar.js** [which uses ArCore]. **I'm using Chrome Canary build with all XR related flags enabled**, but I'm getting this error.

[image: Chrome Canary version] This is the link in the screen https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/ar-for-the-web [For your Reference]

My phone: Xiaomi A3 [Supports ARCore services]

I've tried using Chrome, Chrome Canary build [tested on version 67, 70, 81], Firefox. My point is The google's latest AR demo is working perfectly in chrome canary builds. But why not my local AR app developed using three.ar.js.?

**I've also tried using Google's experimental WebARonARCore browsers**. I'm getting the below error if I use the experimental WebARonARCore browsers from this link https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore.

[image: WebARonARCore Experimental browser]

Answer (score 2):

This is just an assumption, as I am not using three.js for my WebXR experiments, but - the WebXR AR APIs (hit test, plane detection and anchors) are constantly changing.

`xrSession.requestHitTest` was replaced by hit-ray source and hit ray results (see here - https://github.com/immersive-web/hit-test/blob/master/hit-testing-explainer.md) , so the framework you are using needs to adjust to the changes. Canary, being the latest and greatest, implements the newest versions of those APIs, while the older browsers still have the old implementation (probably under a deprecated flag)